# 2006 Civic ex - Wont Start

Tags: honda, electrical, troubleshooting, civic

I'm new to this site and have tried to find my answers. So this is my story.

I've had my 06 civic for 2 years. The 1st six months of having the car. It didn't turn on while getting out of a graveyard shift. I don't know too much about cars as I lived in NYC and used public transit most of my life. Well since I didn't know I went an brought a battery for the car and changed it. It didn't start so i called and autozone mechanic and he told me is was the alternator he changed it in the street and that didn't work either so he tells me its the starter. I go to a new place and get that done now the car is back to normal.

back to the new issues.................

I was parked with my hazard lights on for close to 40 minutes and tried to start the car and it didn't (sad face emoji). I spoke to someone to give me a boost, when he tried the car still didn't start. There is no power whatsoever so I get pushed into a spot in NYC. (yuk) The following day I brought a new battery and the still isn't working. I tried the hazards and the horn they did work but nothing else seems to work.

I was told by a few people that it can be my old problems I have before but I don't want to spend another and and leg on this issue at the moment.

I hope this is read without judgement as I am new owning a Honda.

Thank you very much and hope to get some good info. I will be reading and replying as fast as I can. Good night

Oldman civic

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Until advised, never assume auto store people are experts on repairs unless they're ASE certified. Cars require periodic maintenance; battery cables may corrode to reduce power for starting, spark plugs replaced every 100k miles or less, oil and filter every six months to a year, air filter every 50k miles, tire pressures checked once a month, fuel filter every 100k miles. Battery should be recharged at home using a small charger when it's run down. Try starting fluid into the throttle body. This tests for lack of fuel or spark.

Comment: Thanks. I was told to check the 50amp ignition switch and also check the ground wire for battery. I will be trying to check those this afternoon.